# Скажите как выровнять текст под картинкой чтобы на всех разрешениях выглядело отлично

Tags: css3, html5

[image: внить картинвведите сюда описание изображения]

Скажите как выровнять текст под  картинкой чтобы на всех разрешениях выглядело отлично

подскажите как подключить плагин owl carousel сюда ?

```css
.clinet__title
 font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif
 font-weight: bold
 font-size: 31px
 padding-bottom: 24px
 // white-space: nowrap
 text-align: center
.client__text
 font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif
 font-size: 14px
 // white-space: nowrap
 padding-bottom: 10px

.slice
 position: relative

.owl-carousel .owl-item img
 text-align: center
 width: 95%
 padding: 0 22px
.owl-theme .owl-nav [class*=owl-]
 background-color: transparent 
 color: rgb(155, 155, 155)
 position: absolute
.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-prev
 left: -20px
 top: 268px
.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-next
 right: -4px
 top: 268px

.client__otz
 font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif
 font-size: 14px
 padding-top: 12px
 padding-left: 26px
 padding-right: 26px
 margin-left: 21px
 background-color: red
 // background-color: rgb(246, 248, 253)
 // background-color: red
 max-width: 315px
 // text-align: center
 // max-width: 300px
.client__otz_autor
 font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif
 font-size: 15px
 font-weight: bold
 padding-top: 4px
 display: block
 padding-bottom: 11px
```

```html
<section class="client-section">
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col col-sm-12 slice">
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <div class="item"><img src="https://js.cx/gallery/img2-thumb.jpg" alt="леди">
      <p class="client__otz">
       I have been to this location maybe 3 or 4 times and when I tell you 
       I absolutely LOVE them!! Everyone in there always has such great spirits and make you feel welcome from the moment you walk in the door! I’ve gotten my nose pierced then brought my friend to get her’s done. However this time I got my grandmas …
       <span class="client__otz_autor">
        Claudia M.
       </span>
      </p>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Для начала, все пишет в % а не в px.. ну и следует посмотреть на это https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/ и использовать)

Comment: @Insider у меня не подключен бустрап

Comment: @Leks, ничего не понятно.

Comment: @Insider, ну только бутстрапа и не хватало. Хватит уже всё подряд в код тащить.

Comment: @Qwertiy простите дядя

Comment: @Qwertiy тут используется плагин owl carousel не знаю как тут подключить

Comment: @Qwertiy дядя подскажите как подключить  плагин owl carousel  сюда ?

Comment: @Leks, понятия не имею. В коде вопроса только html и css.

Comment: @Leks, стили поправь (добавь скобки), а так, вот, посмотри: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZPVBVm